# PDF displayed as PHP page losing Signature Certificates

Tags: php, pdf, content-type, php-5.4

I have a workflow that requires a PDF to be opened in a new window (not save as) that needs to be downloadable with all of the properties on it (including Signature Certificates).

If I host the PDF on the server, I can link to that and it does this juts fine. But my requirement is I can't save data to the server.

So here's what I've been doing

**PHP Code:**

```
//$data is the contents of the .pdf file received from a curl request.
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='. $document);
echo $data;
```

**$data:**

```
%PDF-1.4 %ûüýþ 2 0 obj << /ModDate (D:20140715103709) /Author () /Title () /CreationDate (D:20140715103709) /Keywords <> /Creator () /Subject () /Producer (PDFKit.NET 4.0.35.0) >> endobj 4 0 obj << /Parent 3 0 R /Resources 5 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792 ] /Rotate 0 /Contents [6 0 R 7 0 R 8 0 R ] /Type /Page >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Length 4 >> stream q endstream endobj 5 0 obj << /Font << /R8 9 0 R >> /XObject << /X0 10 0 R >> /ProcSet [/PDF /Text ] /ExtGState 11 0 R >> endobj 10 0 obj << /Length 559 /Resources << /XObject << /I0 12 0 R >> /Font << /tallF4 13 0 R /TCADOO+LucidaConsole 14 0 R >> >> /Subtype /Form /FormType 1 /Filter /FlateDecode /Type /XObject /BBox [0.00000 0.00000 612.00000 792.00000 ] >> stream xœµUÛjÜ0}÷Wè½¬#in„@“´¥¥RüVú|”Ý†$m¿¿GZ{/IZ6Ð•°5:’ÆsŽ5Råî]¨})Î?36CAfË,Îf·ªN.‡ß·ÝðåÃ¹ë«iº{Ú>vÕärvíVÏh³fãa¨ÆêðÛøûºóö0‚öÁëw¦6ÚWx=¸}îOéø-÷“Ÿ7Ëå{vÍµ£;eÖQÉDH“šÑ³è`ª¢ŽæU€$fº‰žòDL¬¬hšØ“P.Ùb%‰=À=°Ä˜Îøú‰Xo$g®ý¾å³Ø%äÞµîP©ˆS­ÊÞgM¬ ‘¾R«ðZ­X¸ç‘!a‰„¡ úÐˆÑ’äqÁ8Î¤#°5ªÅó‘ÙŠÃQ4ÿ}pÊŒ¢¤-SADl…{aŠÞQüŒ—¾•¾H,~`A åî¬ìsOYuÐ¬FÈY»ÌÐD“qÎÊ{5¢¦¢2)A>É„Ò7¨YÎ@¨H   ùÖßÈ³bS|iLÅk „ŒšüAEÉ'—¥”Ž©¢•¡ßúÔ±ùÔ”€ôÿ‰Wô¡NTLmàDýK»ƒ›¿óú×)Ú^¼½¼ºzóùWwÛß\Üýx¼[`ÙÌ,¿žzsÞÇmÀ#“ó)U0ˆýÙ7×~Úç»   *ó=„k²ºYZ)àoÎ=æì¾¼(×ÝN·Âuk~sÕä‰wºÛ›Ë|ôîòÎ]Wîú €Ûˆû!ÁÁ.ú¨d endstream endobj 12 0 obj << /Length 5370 /BitsPerComponent 8 /Type /XObject /Width 707 /Subtype /Image /ColorSpace [/Indexed /DeviceRGB 255 15 0 R ] /Mask [251 251 ] /Filter /FlateDecode /Height 234 >> stream xœí=¶«<²†‰˜‘"&s#EDw&1"EžÌŽœ´AÿR É`¤öû|kuŸmc(ŠR©T’Š'îEˆ' ³t]¿>h•—wÝø UØfÂÝ×ÜðÂâ”/À{‰4áé[§ºŽ?Á§Y_Ïl~‚q7áo5é=Lþ8ÛSëŸ`‡}Õ„÷wñq\ƒå»&Ì¾yò†Á5Xd ñ­”Lø+ˆ¯>´Ö^ø[ z?{AÛC¬óôúoia¦Gtp iÂßzl]WÐ¶pÆ:6tÖ|yÖLØeÞ”1|ëìtù«Ç¦œu$ý0QRÖá£aÂ.ß#'N–¾íÏÝ,Îh¿F5øçµk&@ûì ú[³Ò['¼2vÇRŠ½EV`ÃSÚ?cÙ‚@¦à¯ÑÌGO.Uí=ô±õÇ1ëýÏ¼¶½µôß¼ÞÍJD‚/Cþ˜Ÿ™cUëV ~îÜó8ÍBì®3›”b˜«‰…vÍw0Ö"ÈÝ,‰‘Ìkx7ÎO\Pµºf‹ŒIŽË_üí4ø6¢ãæ Ö|TÓÜË”4`eÅX½FLý©*(YÆ"Y°öi®Æ‚¿œÌoÞáÃøú/0êëvF,ƒ[¶^»Öù†(ì)O5ìP£äû;²‰rI*«¶Å®_5bFXI-Šï«ñ©o³Ö‹Ý† !^#7-z“3SÅ¯è©fo1·kÁ*§ö»¡°0,3ûŸA÷(¬•VÃ/«ZÞà³Ix÷Ó&l2I\š­HhÃ¦+ÎwXs½ª ;a•èùÑÑœqÁ&ÊÝŸ%9U)´µ³³ÊãÑ\-Ìõ†8y†–…¿ˆv­N¾(å…7V={Ò[}ykéš^ÈÜ·,ü5L2ßiÀ»   'Wªi#>LTo¶lÂj”üüAf*.X“„úQÞ†‡zíd¿«F·=¬-Çñ×˜)c\²f&Câj^ÕÚ²žëb|›…j¼SÞÍñ’ú¸~èãu15ÌÄÅ´lÂü‡Gs1µ;<Ë+iö<´Ø¹ÞÑœšx6ÉØpóûS‘>¦üA:gMVªú#KÞ>ÎÒ°'ë`ÂsÙÐ`a¥©®f‡ÉŽ{ùcí‰ÎŠ.ûŸœÙM¯àÎ?4a¯s=«yÔßn0,Î1HËÕo×ÎRæfù£¦£ó%gÖûÖ.~y¬)¦¯z=;Ä Z­œ®m{Ñ[IÕ³iÎ)Ìî£´*Ùps¹q´'¾ê†Åð½¬1z¬$® zE1ŽgžÚsÉ^˜eÝÕj,Ø90›q^>bDËÈNÅ´ã'Ýp Ä_ÿÅQ@¼|»\ ú8’0®‡Ùs77@Èï+/Ø4o—É;Çí¿;ªu0 c!þ¯;9¸Y?7°c Äépµ„1ºáÂB q`çloØ?osñÓ˜zun1 œ°ZQ*–3[ö}Êž8‹YzÂ†©-%¬#Kt×Ë ñ½¥œz?‚'váåÆð‡*j—²ÈÅµŽÀSd+Õª¾fÌbdÖivlèÙ<ŒOË*„ß`æË&ló '\žüqiwŸ®zD±~ÄÖ¨Â«i½öÃ8wŒMÓK­©â>Ác µZ33É€x1TšM’3aía‡ô1í…¥ð9µ9ÚŸ¯»¼"^8;¤NžÞzGC2œ,B|ÀÊ 8ÎÕ¾ ˆ„ƒgÆýG½šf7©ëè-Áèr&LLY„hÍò‡sJ0-OMøªÒ`ÌkÏ·Qû¢Ê®–¼%„4abPfÚ ŒZ_"Øtž3á×cé½ëMþ£îíc•ÒšAycºÜØÙh2í­T•mí\È8Ð1óË K/]ü58*Ó¡åN—<£Â½Hé€"å…yip±ºn@5YÂ‘÷±÷ž³gÂîtÜ¦'Za8ÙÚcú  ÃJ™0ëù,Â#¥}Õî~JlX9 ~þÅÂ3‘CRCÏ…‚Þº½dtmåò#†É»T¨×E(ãZ>ó¼°÷iÜvzêÙ¬;^ñ.ïéð¾Â0qù¼ª*B"¿œG¨æýYÖK¡Eé‘SâsA›pñ;!‚˜W7œ‰M³Ø yž^ÉMùñÔÍ®oÕWÊÇÓÿ9ò ó¨ÛJ«=2žA*âØ„élbÿ&IÍë­%D™3ŸEDÉrÑ¢8”H”€2e|!VÊ„uï”Ý­×pÑ”(_°Ä»é `bg»=UY£9–zM/'%ÇÃƒÈD>¥ê ®„²Vâ‚]A(!×Á   m†ÏS×IKô z…jée¬fCxîZ²W³™JÏçøÄd Ad½ývIy/SQ+« ß|ôu7g\5e‚0ë@qTFÂŒŠsÚ,Ó¹öÖ1Õb²i$ú°”ä–+“ÒÍÌG:³õ„ ïJÎ@tgb£¾cÂ]ðíÒqÙ ÇF½p.FXŽ  Õ+ùMW­9XZCõ6Ì¨Q¯YÑÇó$ª~lî¡MÄ-¦… ’j6<È£ì¯çû·K…©¢®ºšû‘°·`"xÃª½UæQWÈªBÙ§-‘"}LXê 3l–X¥ð°“ÇŽQ/ÒÃèóËYw¬÷¨0Å°_ù‚Ø»mÓdÇ×Ò*`LOÅE^˜óø#ÿ@sòAo z”öL8ã…÷ö-;—£øˆìÌÄyƒx ÅO„¾âäÆùÙ\åÃŽã?Ò„ÓBø¡ñ†,vP°‘EL[Ì?}çÁ“&<Å5¾Å“rÂúÛ¬·ªÌp^Þk¶eó\”·†"6üÞ¨±à‚ÌK÷ŸßÔã>|pÔ5„ˆ—æJ7¿37ØR#ºhqYØ\cbÒÕ.&/LJ!¯›õVõ‘1aégò^.~Éº¡gHÄ3^j-M~5ºòÎœë…YÑ1ª¶Öñì¼ urŽP!…×¶FB5qí:N¿Y#Á‰ïôŽ¼öâˆL å5¶ÿÉŒÙ•'³6Lya2pU©|@¶fØªÐ1hwQñù€º›è±‘Ÿ›¤ÉxÄC¯{ÚDrä…é@Â=¬'Œ_g$t‘¥ÞÜDcK$Ž½pÉô²:RªÑÖü¡báÅóTq>YæY_5Êç£×ß§“°Iã"lïHˆÈÙB¤<è¨åä›ü·P¢ —$œÃþ(ã×&œ(d‡›M¥Ô²e$Ì}e#|øaÊ[¬þ©ÖPa\AÎ«*ÿg/y}“v¥ËÑ÷Þ…·séBJ²:H»A´nW‘&c÷S½¼Ðjj\ºÛH†VùÈ&™Žsõ}õÙùÞ°ö³…‘ó]’Ðfm/ ®4©'·/Šºîâ6\}§‰ËÆS€ž,"\<§grU;¼ñžöÞãa„?éC{5³(îQr—¹H4ƒÒÆV—zá¢ðÈË$P^hÂÁúœY?ˆÌ‘4õ?ï-®ì²îÙáŒ¼°\\¢…X!Öa³ÔÀÁÔ†»ÒDqÞã¡N0z5Ùuï¨å2Õwuµ(ÉHt¥+ÜªjT ¦ ‚UQ›Eïî~>~Ð²çþ*vYù‡~8ªcv,Äèß¨éV2óù^mÜ"Uf$ÌD —V&œ±7áŠ9öÂzº¾tŒêh<Û0xÚN6ÓÝîÎ{õw oOíjA£‡yác!üÃíüQÉ|>7¿¸&O­žŠÆšæ—ž³U£çý‰%Õ^š@6õÔ·ª/;Ldº8%rJ¼pïýi#ãã½_¤§rÌW+†)?L•R=¥…XÌáæsn…Ûn2=;çyHcˆîñä}’&4Ì>ç”nK¿py÷¸ÎK<èo‘ÒB0s¸G†Íòœ±ùÈV}»h3ô4AšpPpXj2êÊÔ>ç”–LëWII,|Ü·xÏCjO<ßˆ…™û‡›V¥ô$ôš.p2ûy“c´ Ó_8½ÑÛ?¸ë=Ý-@Al™Ý‰=í‘£K%ùsE´¶ÂVY$%3¯u|_‹ªM—6áÀm9ƒ¿¾ÚâýeÎ½'fQß²L½‹‹ÑœòUaâœÍ¾žfµúdjõT˜P¨4^×·Oê®ô-‘ÓuÏÐ„¹Ò›{Ø>3ŠKh¨?øNUþª²TU®‚êÁºYë ¾ëG}à…¹ÿ§Œýü—hI©þCýÚú?ßé®ý²–Õ‰7,×.xMìH': 2Ê¤)HGí6“µ³™ûqÑ§3Ø­U/÷4w4I{39Ò×Y#>Z§°?ªçäºi9ÌS»A‚çg#½p,A-ô‘Ç¤¦òWòÓ3Œ”Jü¦ÎBý©]J,m"7i©c\•©Éa£»á-iÂîŒˆm<›º•vi™)(û–½m­u´s^8UàNÝ=°`©›ûŸšàJ»Á~‡©,ØìL ÷åuS3•ùó€,'„ †àÎ…ê}nNX¶j=9%XäÒÝ:¸vqŠnÕêÿ’CUï¾ã9UY¨Ú­ÙRìÑ*¨5NXJÌ;Úé|óì7t3XéýÏÍþIÇû«0Ót¦Q«ê»øàg"¥ç¦€ÓBèƒÌnÂ°ò°ö¥Ží+žžNÊv4ÿ’ŠÐÕ’:tu4iƒ®í†L‘‚ìWEÑ¾¬;q¶µÒ¨a’Û¿¨‚ä³ÝBFºi»åôä‹6Úû¥Ë<šQ[$2#?=y&7œB×-â±öT¼ìODl·êŒôöÅÖÂ¹ÖÀ”ûMdlâ®tkªÌ:ÊIL…/WÚf<ÂeôîML)ì®7!öÅmôþ“W[  Õé+Pf‹ð#¹tn2—~½ç€ôÂnÑ‹Œ³‘¿×æé –‘é•É:‰±8…®½ZÆNZ½(9î5MÛ5Åý•b„¾P]âÐ| *³*óÁ†8/°Zýí2£÷,ý0ú!-ÊP?jùJ”:.VÁíý¯Ðÿ‰³Þb‰—¸‘&ìn¨„p;ñ‰:S·Ý™™"áú'L“mVGÛÊèDRÎ.þ:Õ‡U\IÑcïðWü_P½v!³%¦ç× Õz{ï5Í®¥r ¶ëgp°}³‹áÆ2è\Ç  mKþIå ·"ÊC¶žTb«›³WP‰oÇvîåH]ébáK¸^`Ö3fOkÈD|Æ©    ü¤^>BÚ’Çœï¼R¢‘!è£T°µQ\"¢'m¢I‰ÅZ¬L[V*®)TÚÕÿ»9žÛf%&.'ú§.d•¬€¸Ž|­©4‡’Y—À˜X¢s5ímÅu÷YêSš lXÖyˆöØø‡¾™’ðgÎ‰ýÓÂ^"#„ì{Œ5^,Ph´¼²ó_L³ÌÓ¬õ“è#œJ)„«µIB®s6Ã§è5ân'ß,`”Ïýß¤|«9L?ÙÖ¹}¦=—Gpÿ" ëÖÞóTÀN–Œ5—ÞÛZ‘"á«wÜ·‘˜òøvÔÊ6ˆ&ºM»S#Õñg“OòfL´ É2ìõß¼èóJZyï×d¤ZÙ’6¼ùUî«ˆÊ„gO™Ì:ñíÖ¬{ÝØCÚCN¯jÉÏ°³®¨›âÆ¡W;›á#»—‚g¶UKµË)vhS™X÷ÖûÙ_þ+üè!ŸÍûµ”Ü•a íÌ. ¡tÄ;öv†ddY‘ “çæ3¶oÞLõrec³eÜNÕ×;›á“ÙÍœÖÏŸ­›¯a]IŠ@¼ÙYÅ.J®ø|¤m’5ê+×Tºìœßé†ýÔ¯'•È(S”ï MÄ’·Ÿ|1»®¿ß”é{)Âj!"úSB|ùž—îíqëÿ6ì{J_º‘g2(xUt€¿~Áa|î)!ÎÀ»ÃI¶Ÿ£0d=ÿ³ë³?±Îêw>u¾V#Ó¢xÃ÷iXÙ®ÅúÍ±çòuMo¯ˆ0ë[Þt€ÚïÎÜ1à3³QW„8Å'ìÂº–C+®§ä†ÖÏ;vüÌ°à’à2SËZ_LXxjsW8‰}nA@ D³ÊlÖ°Ö™  ]ƒ þ…Œ× øºà*‚×¾œ.Éì¤xßí6¸ñlZæºàgÙv´¹KÇûå|ÔÆšó™“Pˆ“/"?ÉhC ìû9’!.ME}Dð£03—ª]þ+B€6ƒV·D¡UÚdszzv[6« !@£8AhªbËÚdu:íñ®.¼ !@£p§Ó¾­¯BÐ(½ÿž–{RUÚdþûû oØgP… Q˜»/[… MÜ!·£ª4Êh—„=nGU!h”¡s6»ßåÿª´É^DZ¸ÍÿU!hg«É}þ¯ !@£lNOî–™€[ü_B€F±{Vå¦á[Ò±UÅ¼R‚ßh> stream xœMÌ½ Â@à~ŸbË¤ðÜÇþ´‚v  ×‰UÐTWÄäýñ<”„i>†Ù‘B‘¾ùcÌp§jÃõ‡÷3ÄÀ"¢µØ{ÌxNåÐÐƒ»[Äô*4²:`Ô•9¸`ÊpoÖöÀåÁÉ´yn\6®­âGºÁ%A_òE©$ endstream endobj 15 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 380 >> stream xœE’±±e1BéÇ!µ¸êp´ ZHU{ßOV™G3Ào0 8À!ŽpŒœâ—¸Â5np‹<â   ÏxÁ+b„1&˜b%VXcƒí÷7JT¨Ñ ßãÓ&!ÂD¾xÈ#ó„§¼à%¯xÍÞò|â3_øÊ‡qÌ  §\pÉ×ÜpË‚%+ÖlØÏÇw6  òÙÒu¤cèTºÔ•®u£[=èQOzÖ‹^5ÐP#5ÑT-µÒZmU¨T¥Zú!øˆÓa#øÐG>ö‰O}áK_ùÚ7¾õƒýäg¿øÕ=òØO½ðÒ+¯½ñÖ…KW®Ý¸ý/l ä#9ÌQŽs’Ó\ä2W¹ÎMnóÇ<å9/yÍ ÃŒ2Î$Ó,²Ì*ël²M‘2Uê4iEøÒø|¾¾åW…ƒö¨Ç=éi/zÙ«^÷¦·}ècŸúÜ—¾vÐaGwÒi]vÕu7ÝŸØW´/íùw÷Ÿøÿù=PxÌ endstream endobj 11 0 obj << /R7 16 0 R >> endobj 16 0 obj << /OPM 1 /Type /ExtGState >> endobj 13 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /BaseFont /Helvetica /Name /tallF4 >> endobj 14 0 obj << /Name /TCADOO+LucidaConsole /Type /Font /Subtype /Type0 /BaseFont /LucidaConsole /Encoding /Identity-H /ToUnicode 17 0 R /DescendantFonts [18 0 R ] >> endobj 17 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 664 >> stream xœ­TKoÛ0¾ÈàÚC§C‹¡À–´˜m‚¦{ÃªD'ÚlÉ äþ÷£äGÝ†a:2õ‘üøIäÑ›õfòNÙ'œœMx@g+’8YÜ‰r<::ZZYhü=¢BÕ»+X“•ôp¼H—©Ñþ$ S#óJa{õ·Úì1!§Š³h_O>DÌ£ö9Ÿ˜!²„ÎIÄ}BrÚš+˜O“$ –…-kÒÛ¿‚É¿¯A¤~óËËdÂŸ‹–Ï¦v\º¥Ò’ð¨¦ïwyaë‚ÀHÏ¿@kŽb½F£´Ùþ{¿zL7Mm2K…ð¬Hk¼ÐìPÐü¡$["ùzÆf_Ð-R¡]¸†cKÂ°0 TÚyÒOU¤Ä9üŽ!™ÎqƒY=k~a @örëµÄ·àbÚ‚ÂFzF ¢øð±ÈP|Tð0%ÂDîY’‡c…x5ddÐÁÚˆJëÄ¸ÕúK,mýÚOû ºW·ãÑOR2÷ endstream endobj 18 0 obj << /W 19 0 R /FontDescriptor 20 0 R /Type /Font /Subtype /CIDFontType2 /BaseFont /LucidaConsole /CIDToGIDMap 21 0 R /CIDSystemInfo << /Ordering (Identity) /Supplement 1 /Registry (Adobe) >> >> endobj 20 0 obj << /StemV 0 /Flags 4 /ItalicAngle 0.00000 /Type /FontDescriptor /Descent -210 /FontName /LucidaConsole /CapHeight 789 /Ascent 789 /FontFile2 22 0 R /FontFamily (Lucida Console) /FontBBox [0 -210 630 789 ] >> endobj 22 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 1413 /Length1 1784 >> stream xœSoPTU?÷½ûîþy»ûþ,»+(=Å ²,¸ÉfKM¢¶‹¢!¨`Œ:IŽbæ‡HF§‘°ÄlÆŠµi†)(¥ÉqÐ&É¡Éú 3NcƒSì£³àŸö¡óÞïÞsÎ»ïÞßýÝs€Z¹fCeuõ¼çŽcæ("¯âZî6úWn©«ªäçSúw   [+›ëÉI2@â¹”ª¦†”§¯,oÇ8ãÛõÛ6Ô»^º  €KÁØØ´åµûŽ;rxŒùŽš­ Íë…Jv6>ÿÆúM[çòcœ<ÍM8"g['þÑ›DFÇ6=>nØ³°9z`êA¼ÿåžYn|r >!V&dð®ÍðâºÈ8âæ.õÁ¯S¿!Æ×^H¥‹é*á¼0Î2XÈh4ÖÀAD‘ÍgSwM8×Yˆ,™úŸûàø]o&„\èSð5tÃ9š‰ä#¸Žœ'8 ‘zØU\wÃ†6’NžÂì È‡.èájá,dà¿kŒ(ì„eP¯CÞ‚ð)ìâÞg!˜ é´“{–r¿ð<ÎüI‡ hƒnŽaÜÁOPïAsð™$kµV¾Ì«˜½šäðjv›W­Yš•Ù5¦i<—¥YÌ@–fbYZÕúr©bõ¨´¶yTj^]*-W;¥'Õ^’\$Ô[Ò¢üQ©DujÅr¢’;¥m®!i½ü’´N•Ê°_…})b1"_>+=}Ž/þ¿$ùäÝ’c'B‘{I08[Rå$YU5iNýœúäÖdª±:ö!ãsH”L¹¨¤ì9CÞ‰¼y î¶&G¶o'düWK7^ü–!&]Ñ•4lpC±W¸•±ÓüAÚ:SwEÆ0mc861hƒeœ/sT¾Ã d[ˆ—Ð¶Éšü–q§ÇT‚•V7uV   ã ‚çúYˆq‚Í*»lIršm®¼×¶O6ÛTd•‰Å¡*2ŸÍs|‚|µb|çÄ*dW© ÈàË‰·§(²ŽàjÇŒqâ#Nc|Œ¤ÃÆpé"Õ¤Šœ0VÇŒ£Fy×Ä5ÄÞŽµÏì#Šw§ùX 7èyA ”˜‰¨@qu“ÌQàÜV9®gaSäê¬‘€Á½Årß¥>äáóëŠàOStW”ì7¹0ÙßAwEZ¢Ü1=7Ê9ó'B}0ÔÄ7Ñ½ü^J] Š‡òŒäzBžROµ§Á³ÇÃî%âA Õ!zIâfÖÂÚ¯(L$Iòõþ‘XE¿¢.œÖ"€ÎBoâ¨€û^œ[^Éóç>æM5ùó|9nW“3é®î–?#½š~ß{æÇ‰mm¥dq=7oE¾:÷êÁšÓ+~ý¢ñâ®ç‡zâç…úàÝ+Ø!Ì,·¿lßaßo§vÊlª… @©U7ˆÛÅÝ"y3³:©·ãl}“¹¯¥CrY¸~ÈËËO|ŠÏåUˆ®pÃ±Ã\mt` ¶‡|Göwñ‡'_ì@M5®sú¬ˆk‡!7äç˜UéY;¯º»Ëf]ÊÊgW&©`u{¬Ü5ÓËNÄä¦‘Y±Ùi~·/'Ï/ë©&<5]IWxS‰ãäÆ–cÆŠ4÷eìa$Û¸y©Ñ|rÉ7ï’"Ê}{Êh5îü>hÜÆ3½€š"ò‚I@Í‚“YËèfÚBÛ)¥f³ †@pÛ°¸‚KË3ûŸìÃ‹¡/&N¢ûu—   x’¨nî#þX¿3ÛðævN’.%Úž1VÒ!Ôwâ(BÔ!¢ˆîŸ8°¿ð¹&ezSÚÛÃeº>»0™—Y´²¬04[×#óP¶Uàp endstream endobj 19 0 obj [32 [602 ] 47 [602 602 602 602 ] 52 [602 602 ] 55 [602 ] ] endobj 21 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 171 >> stream xœíÉ¹ !AÇ×ÅP    ÁL`­äÜúŽoÉŸš¶«gìžµõÅ% endstream endobj 9 0 obj << /FirstChar 101 /FontDescriptor 23 0 R /Type /Font /LastChar 116 /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /CXJIBR+Courier /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Widths [600 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 600 600 ] >> endobj 23 0 obj << /StemV 77 /AvgWidth 600 /FontName /CXJIBR+Courier /CapHeight 563 /ItalicAngle 0 /XHeight 431 /MaxWidth 600 /FontFile3 24 0 R /CharSet (/e/s/t) /Ascent 563 /Type /FontDescriptor /Descent -16 /MissingWidth 600 /FontBBox [0 -16 519 563 ] /Flags 131105 >> endobj 24 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Subtype /Type1C /Length 632 >> stream xœcd`ab`ddäpÎ/-ÊL-±uH3þaú!ËÜ]ýcöã¬²&y¼=<ŒÝ<ÌÝ<,~² }oü^Ãÿ½\€™‘±¢w–s~AeQfzF‰‚FhP¸¦¶¶BÄÐÒÒR!©&£à’Zœ™ž§ d”¥æää¦æ•X+8Uçäd&+¤çTd+$¦¤¤¦€´…%æ¤f+¸eædä—)h8k*ê  #¿ÌÜ¤Òbßü¼|… ÔôÒœÄ"Aæâ’T††P7°oXŽ2*2–ÿxÃ÷ãMõ–¢ï²ßõ¿lú´¥|Ç÷u»Ä…§ýpù!*š±*nVP7‡°›¦S´WöÜ¼å•òË«–·\m9Ü²´eiíÒš9EÝ%ÂÓÂ¼RLÌ\7ì”›Ä.ì6½yj½œ°WmKc•¼_1©y¦œp×ŒI“çÉOcßš¶§êl7ÇwÖû‡o¬)_›³P>{Aê4ÿIÆSZ{KgÍ*›Ñ0gŽÔÖÃ«¯^ßŸ?ANX©ºwRóté“¦Î•žv‘]XinË”:9áiõM@Àøþyãwý­Ìß#˜Š~çfŸ×:¹¦¦µ±Jî7·#{ESK]í”–yòW/ds8ýâÁw¶+¦6Oklëèlo‘K*v­ îæpK\³Oþûüïùìs§Lš9£iR%Ôl§-ßµ¶0þ˜ý=Z´{gçüšÕ÷¬÷iwsüQ×ÿÍ÷[ì›Êwégßyv¯Ú4µ©µ½³­E>9Û©Ô·û7C·õùÚ¯[Xæ½¸täM÷›î«³ 8øÊçÿ0ÿ]hþüùlÛ¸¶poãáÙÂÃËÀ ’    endstream endobj 8 0 obj << /Length 17 >> stream Q q /X0 Do Q endstream endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Count 1 /Kids [4 0 R ] >> endobj 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Metadata 25 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 25 0 obj << /Type /Metadata /Subtype /XML /Length 3527 >> stream ï»¿ PDFKit.NET 4.0.35.0 1.4 2014-07-15T10:37:09-07:00 2014-07-15T10:37:09-07:00 2014-07-15T10:37:09-07:00 application/pdf endstream endobj xref 0 26 0000000000 65535 f 0000012203 00000 n 0000000015 00000 n 0000012145 00000 n 0000000187 00000 n 0000000370 00000 n 0000000317 00000 n 0000006879 00000 n 0000012078 00000 n 0000010881 00000 n 0000000480 00000 n 0000007530 00000 n 0000001298 00000 n 0000007609 00000 n 0000007721 00000 n 0000007077 00000 n 0000007563 00000 n 0000007891 00000 n 0000008628 00000 n 0000010562 00000 n 0000008837 00000 n 0000010637 00000 n 0000009061 00000 n 0000011085 00000 n 0000011356 00000 n 0000012269 00000 n trailer << /Root 1 0 R /ID [(a3116cc2-80a0-4b86-a776-a39e4d9b5de0) (a3116cc2-80a0-4b86-a776-a39e4d9b5de0) ] /Info 2 0 R /Size 26 >> startxref 15879 %%EOF 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Metadata 25 0 R /Pages 3 0 R /AcroForm 26 0 R >> endobj 26 0 obj << /Fields [27 0 R] /SigFlags 3>> endobj 4 0 obj << /Parent 3 0 R /Resources 5 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Rotate 0 /Contents [6 0 R 7 0 R 8 0 R] /Type /Page /Annots [27 0 R] >> endobj 27 0 obj << /F 132 /Type /Annot /Rect[0 0 0 0] /FT /Sig /Subtype /Widget /P 4 0 R /T(ENVELOPEID_803CFF4853384DF5AA509C4BF2F2B075) /AR.SigFieldData(AM\(0\)LM\(0\)ETF\(0\)DF\(dd MMM yyyy\)TF\(hh:mm:ss\)SL\(Signed by: \)RL\(Reason: \)DL\(Date & Time: \)TI\(\)FLG\(0\)) /TU (Digital signature by CoSign®) /V 28 0 R >> endobj 28 0 obj << /Filter /Adobe.PPKMS /Contents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rop_Build << /App << /Name /ARX#20CoSign® >> /Filter << /Name /AR.SAPI >> >>/FT /Sig /Name(DocuSign, Inc.) /M(D:20140715103708-07'00') /ByteRange[0 17207 25175 560] /Reason(Digitally verifiable PDF exported from www.docusign.com) /SubFilter /adbe.pkcs7.detached >> endobj xref 1 1 0000016563 00000 n 4 1 0000016697 00000 n 26 3 0000016646 00000 n 0000016843 00000 n 0000017164 00000 n trailer << /Root 1 0 R /ID [(a3116cc2-80a0-4b86-a776-a39e4d9b5de0) (a3116cc2-80a0-4b86-a776-a39e4d9b5de0)] /Info 2 0 R /Size 29 /Prev 15879 >> startxref 25452 %%EOF
```

If you go to Print as PDF in Chrome, the Signature Certificate tab is not in Reader.

If I host this same file on the server and access the .pdf link externally it works just fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What has this to do with "Print as PDF in Chrome"? Could you provide an example that may let us reproduce this issue?

Comment: I can't find a sandbox that will allow me to set headers and this code is internal. You can repro it through php locally with what I gave above.

Comment: A PDF file includes binary data... so it's impossible to use the code above. Again: What has this to do with "Print as PDF in Chrome"?

Comment: The PDF displays fine, you can Print as PDF in Chrome and it downloads the PDF... but it doesn't download the Signature Certificate data, just the flattened PDF image from what I can tell.

Comment: `echo` to a certain degree interprets data in its arguments. As PDFs, especially their compressed streams, may contain virtually any combination of bytes, there might well be some byte sequences specially interpreted and replaced by PHP `echo`.

Comment: if I change Content Disposition from inline to attachment it downloads the PDF fine through echo, so I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of when you open the PDF document in Chrome it is actually opened by the "[Chrome PDF Viewer](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1060734?hl=en)" plugin. It is NOT OPENED via Adobe's "PDF Plugin".

When you use the "[Print As PDF](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1379552?hl=en)" functionality it *will make a snapshot/screenshot/picture* of what is displayed on your browser and *saves it as .pdf*. The saved file is a image-based PDF. So actually by using 'Save as PDF' you DO NOT SAVE the same document to your computer and thus the digital meta data is lost.
  If you open the doc and use "Save page as" (`Ctrl+Shift+S`) or just "Save" (`Ctrl+S`) and download it to your disk the digital meta information should be there.

This is typical browser misconception. If you want to open pdf files with "Adobe's PDF Plugin" you will need to do is to disable the "Chrome PDF Viewer". Go to `chrome://plugins/` - there you will see the plugin's name and a 'disable' link. This way [Chrome will use Adobe's PDF Plugin](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142056?hl=en).

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than how I thought it worked. I need this to work on all computers nativly. So my only options are to host the file and display as a PDF it OR have change to `Content-Disposition: attachment` for an auto save?

Comment: Well you need to educate your users that there are limits to what you can do. 
The 'auto-download' should occur ONLY when  `Content-Disposition: attachment`is used in a response with the `Content-type:application/octet- stream`. This [is by spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1), how the browsers implement it is another thing.